# Macro to set the range based on non blank cell in adjacent coulmn

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to add an excel formula in column N if cell in column M is not blank, currently I have this below code which will add from N2 to N7302 but I want to have this formula based on the criteria range what I have mentioned, please help.

```
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'Service ID Master List'!C[-11],1,0),""Fail"")=""Fail"",""Check SESE_ID"",IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Rules!C[-13],1,0),""Fail"")=""Fail"",""Check SESE_RULE"",IF(AND(RC[-5]<>"" "",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-5],Rules!C[-13],1,0),""Fail"")=""Fail""),""Check SESE_RULE_ALT"",IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'Service ID Master List'!C3:C6,4,0),""Fail"")=""Fail"",""Check SEPY_ACCT_CAT"",IF(RC[-7]=""TBD"",""Check SEPY_ACCT_CAT"",""Pass"")))))"
Range("N2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N7302")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add formulas to multiple cells in one step, thus avoiding the loop.  To identify non-empty cells, you can use `SpecialCells`, again avoiding the need for a loop.

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    sFormula = "YourFormulaString"

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("M2")
        Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = sFormula
    ' If needed, uncomment next line
    'rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = sFormula
End Sub
```

The above code assumes cells in column M contain Constants.  If needed you can repeat with `xlCellTypeFormulas`